# How to create MongoBD Schema for typescript interface with "alternative types"?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following typescript interface:

```
interface IDataItem {
  id: string;
  value: boolean | number | string;
  temp: boolean;
}
```

For simplicity, let's consider a simple array of data like this:

```
const MyData: IDataItem[] = [
  {
    id: '1',
    value: false,
    temp: false,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    value: 'Test',
    temp: true,
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    value: 42,
    temp: false,
  },
];
```

How can I save this data to a MongoDB using mongoose? I have experience creating "Schemas" with typescript interfaces with "unique types" but not "alternative types" (such as `boolean | number | string`).

To be more specific: What do I have to put where the question marks are?

```
const schema = new Schema<IData>({
  id: { type: String, required: true },
  value: ???,
  temp: {type: Boolean, required: true },
});
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you can use mixed type for multiple types for a field it's like any(in Ts) probably not exactly what you want i guess but anyway:

```
value : {type : Schema.Types.Mixed}
```

also recommend to take a look at [Mongoose Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) for Mixed type